# Scrapy css selector can't find result - but browser can

Tags: scrapy, css-selectors

Can't figure out why the following selector in scrapy fails:

```
>>> response.css('a[href="./viewforum.php?f=18"]::text')[0].get()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But the same thing works for the same page using Chrome:

```
> $$('a[href="./viewforum.php?f=18"]')[0].innerText
'Contribute and help the VideoLAN project'
```

To reproduce, use the following webpage:

```
scrapy shell "https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=29792"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [1]: response.css('a[href*="./viewforum.php?f=18"]::text').get()                                                    
Out[1]: 'Contribute and help the VideoLAN project'
```

**Edit:**

```
a[href="./viewforum.php?f=18"]:
Selects every <a> element whose href attribute value is "./viewforum.php?f=18"

a[href*="./viewforum.php?f=18"]:
Selects every <a> element whose href attribute value contains the substring "./viewforum.php?f=18"
```

Since the href value is "./viewforum.php?f=18&sid=be611e......0d35", and we want to match the value without the 'sid' part we use the selector '*='.